# Get id of tab using button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, jquery-ui-tabs

I have the following code which gets the id of the currently selected jquery-ui-tab:

```
$($('[id^="tab"], [id^="home"]')).live('click', function() {
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

As you can see, I have 2 sets of tabs, tab(n) and home(n).

This works fine, except that I need to be able to get the id at any point in time, not when the tab is selected, the code above only gets the id when a tab is selected.

How do I get the id of the jquery-ui-tabs home(n) and tab(n) using a standard button clicked i.e.

```
$("#button_one").click(function(event) { 
    // get id of selected tab
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.ui-tabs-selected').prop('id');
```

jQuery version < 1.6:

```
$('.ui-tabs-selected').attr('id');
```

Note that I would change your first function to:

```
$($('[id^="tab"], [id^="home"]')).live('click', function() {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

And don't use `live` unless your jQuery version is < 1.4.4

---

A way to get the index:

> ...retrieve the index of the currently selected tab

```
var $tabs = $('#example').tabs();
var selected = $tabs.tabs('option', 'selected');
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  I'm still using jQuery version < 1.4.4.

Comment: @oshirowanen: In that case, you should mention that you're using an ancient version of jQuery whenever you ask a jQuery question.